# Jest mockImplementation is not a function but works with require

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking, es6-modules

I'm writing a test using jest and TS and I want to mock a function from a module, with two different implementations for two tests, although when using import I have an error saying `mockImplementation is not a function`

BUT, if I import the module with require, everything works. Can someone explain me why?

The snippet below works, but if I change the `require` to `import { execSync } from 'child_process'` the error appears

```
jest.mock('child_process', () => {
  return {
    execSync: jest.fn(),
  };
});

const packageToMock = require('child_process');

packageToMock.execSync.mockImplementation(() => {
      return something
 });
```

Also could I have this mock behaviour with spyOn? how?